# fadeIn() not working in an external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Question Background**

I have a simple scenerio where a user submits a form which in turn appends a spinner GIF to a div.

**The Issue:**

If I add the jQuery and JavaScript code to the page inside `<script>` tags it works fine. **If I add it to an external JavaScript file that I include in the page the fadeIn() and hide() methods won't fire.**

**Code:**

```
@model ShopComparisonEngine.Models.HomePageVM
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.png">
    <title>Compzee</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/navmenu-push.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/CompzeeHomeStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/navmenu-push.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Images/Favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Images/Favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="centerDiv" class="centered">
        <div class="col-lg-12 centered-text">
            <h1>Compzee <img src="~/Images/CompzeeLogoSmall.png" class="logoSize" /></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Compare", "ShopComparator", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "searchForm", onsubmit = "showSpinner()" }))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchTerm, new { id = "searchTerm", @class = " form-control", placeHolder = "Item to search for" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.searchTerm)

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-5 form-group">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.searchCatagory, new SelectList(new List<string> {
                                 "All",
                            "Baby",
                            "Business, Office & Industrial",
                            "Cameras & Photography",
                            "Clothes & Accessories",
                            "Comics, Books & Magazines",
                            "Computers & Tablets",
                            "Consoles",
                            "DVD's, Films & TV",
                            "Garden & Patio",
                            "Health & Beauty",
                            "Holiday & Travel",
                            "Home",
                            "Kitchen",
                            "Jewellery",
                            "Mobile Phones & Accessories",
                            "Musical Instruments",
                            "Music",
                            "Pet Supplies",
                            "Shoes",
                            "Sporting Goods",
                            "Toys & Games",
                            "Vehicle Parts & Accessories",
                            "Video Games",
                            "Watches",
                           }), "Select Catagory", new { id = "searchCat", @class = "form-control " })

                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.searchCatagory)

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 form-group">

                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.countryCode, new SelectList(new List<string> {
                                "UK",
                                "US",
                                "FR",
                                "DE",
                           }), "Select Country", new { id = "searchCountry", @class = "form-control " })

                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.countryCode)

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" id="compzeeSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Compzee!" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h4>Compzee allows you to search for your favourite items and compare the prices between ebay and Amazon.</h4>
            <img src="~/Images/ebaySmall.png" class="marketPlace"/>
            <img src="~/Images/amazonSmall.png" class="marketPlace" />
        </div>
        <div id="loadSpinner" class="text-center">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="validationCheck" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CompzeeHomepageJS.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript - CompzeeHomepageJS.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#validationCheck').val('false');
});


function showSpinner() {

    $('#searchForm').submit(function () {

        if (!$(this).valid()) {

            return false;
        }
        else {

            $("#compzeeSubmit").prop('disabled', true);

            if ($("#validationCheck").val() !== "true") {

                $("#validationCheck").val("true");

                var spinner = '<img src="/Images/LoadingSpinner.gif">';

                $('#loadSpinner').hide();

                $(spinner).appendTo('#loadSpinner');

                $('#loadSpinner').fadeIn(1000);

                return true;
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in developer console in your browser? Usually, you can find an answer in this error.

Comment: @tilz0R thanks for the reply. I thought of that too but no errors in the console.

Comment: Have you tried `$('#loadSpinner').hide().append(spinner).fadeIn();`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney thanks for you comment. That does indeed work in the view but still wont work in the external JavaScript file. I feel it must be some kind of JQuery loading issue but have no idea how.

Comment: ok, try commenting out the other 3 scripts loaded after `CompzeeHomepageJS.js` and see if it works then - also, how exactly is `showSpinner()` called?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I've added the entire View (im using ASP.NET MVC) interestingly enough if I remove those three lines for the validation checks (unobtrusive) then i dont get the spinner at all.

Comment: @user1352057 try to add a full url path for your image LoadingSpinner.gif

Comment: [Playaround here](http://output.jsbin.com/huwijadoka) I recommend you to put the image in your html file. (show Playaround)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the jquery inside the head tags and your personal scripts at the end of the page.
And in every case your page must first load the jquery then your scripts that use jquery.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but the issue is still present.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out. The Validation check in document.ready was firing before jQuery was loaded. Removing the document.ready solved the issue.